# How to remove the quiet flag in xelatex in nbconvert to pdf

Tags: jupyter, nbconvert

Hello I know when I run `jupyter nbconvert --to pdf foo.ipynb` it firsts constructs a notebook.tex and required resources and then runs `xelatex notebook.tex -quiet`

However if xelatex crashes, well you end up with:

```
nbconvert.exporters.pdf.LatexFailed: PDF creating failed, captured latex output:
Failed to run "xelatex notebook.tex -quiet" command:
```

Or no information what's so ever. Ive had it happen to be before sometimes where I accidently copied some strange Unicode characters into my notebook, or when I was missing a required xelatex package, or a faulty expression. I have no way of knowing these issues unless I convert to tex first and then see the errors pop up on the tex-> pdf conversion.

is there a way to remove the `-quiet` tag so I know what the issues and can address them directly without doing a round about notebook -> tex -> pdf conversion?

I tried setting, `!jupyter nbconvert --to pdf foo.ipynb --Application.log_level=10` and `!jupyter nbconvert --to pdf foo.ipynb --log-level INFO` but the `-quiet` flag still keeps getting passed to xelatex.